# interpretation of Significance level (Type I error probability) from pwr.t.test()

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, false-discovery-rate

I was looking at the sig.level=Significance level (Type I error probability)
from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pwr/versions/1.3-0/topics/pwr.t.test

Can someone please explain me is Significance level () equal to P value or FDR or what is relation between ?

I know that FDR depends on the p-value threshold and also on the truth and that False discovery rate (FDR) is the expected proportion of Type I errors.

if
Type 1 Error Rate = "Probability of rejecting the null if it's true" = p-value threshold

and

Type 1 Error Rate = False Discovery Rate IF the null hypothesis is true
and probability of making Type I error is .

Also if my  is 0.05 which means that that I want the probability that a null finding will be called significant to be less than 5%. In other words, I want the probability of a type I error, or a false positive, to be less than 5%.

How then do I explain  in relation to p value or FDR?

Comment: It is $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I edited it

Comment: So is your question about the relationship between $\alpha$, false discovery rate, and p-value?

Comment: Yes, indeed that is my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The false discovery rate (FDR) is the expected proportion of type I errors, which is where you incorrectly reject the null hypothesis.

α is the p-value you choose to use.  You have defined it as 0.05, which is a common choice.  At this p-value, there's a 5% chance of a Type 1 error.